# Slick2d's TiledMap.getTileProperty's String "def" field

Tags: java, slick2d

I am trying to use Slick2d to write a basic game am using the Tiled tilemap editor to make the game terrain.  Each type of tile in the map has a property known as "id" with a known string as a value.

I am using Slick2d's method:

```
TiledMap.getTileProperty(int tileID, java.lang.String propertyName, java.lang.String def)
```

to get the property of an individual tile.  I believe my implementation works, but does anyone know what the "def" field should be?  I think propertyName should be "id" and tileID being the getTileId method.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`def`means default value. If the value isn't set this value gets used.